# picking out subject + adjective pairs from a sentence using nlp

Tags: python, node.js, machine-learning, nlp

Is there a package in python or node.js that can extract pairs of subjects and adjectives. For example, using this sentence:

> "Unlike an orange, an apple is not juicy but it does have crunch."

I'm hoping to extract something along the lines of:

```
{ 
orange: 'juicy',
apple: 'crunchy'
}
```

Is this functionality available in any nlp library already, or can I train a classifier somehow? thx for the advice stack wizards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something along the lines of:

http://www.nltk.org

for Python. This is definitely a dense subject area! Good luck

Comment: Thanks. I've had a look at this module and a couple of others and none seem to do what I'm attempting. I think I'll have to build the module myself (and share on npm of course :-) ).

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for it :)